# Why if passing an object param to another class without having a copy constructor ruins some fields inside the object?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

Recently I was working on a project that involved passing arguments by value in C++ and something strange was happening when trying to access the argument fields. The code looked like this:

```
int main (){
    int sizes[] = {2, 3};
    Topology top;
    top.set_dim(2); // 2D topology
    top.set_sizes(sizes); // 2 rows and 3 columns

    Architecture arch;
    arch.set_topology(top);
}
```

The Topology class looks like this (it does not have a copy constructor, so I assume it will be generated automatically by the compiler and will be a shallow one, only copying the pointer address, not the data inside):

```
class Topology {
    public: 
        Topology();
        ~Topology();

        void set_dim(int);
        void set_sizes(int*);

        int get_dim();
        int* get_sizes();

    private:
        int dim;
        int *sizes;
};

Topology::Topology(){

}
Topology::~Topology(){ 
    if (sizes != NULL) 
        delete sizes; 
}
void Topology::set_dim(int dim_){
    dim = dim_;
}
void Topology::set_sizes(int *sizes_){ 
    sizes = new int[dim];
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++){
        sizes[i] = sizes_[i];
    }
}
int Topology::get_dim(){
    return dim;
}
int* Topology::get_sizes(){ 
    return sizes;
}
```

The Architecture class is the following:

```
class Architecture {
    public: 
        Architecture();
        ~Architecture();

        void set_topology(Topology top);

    private:
        Parallelization p;
};

Architecture::Architecture(){

}
Architecture::~Architecture(){

}
Architecture::set_topology(Topology top){
    p.set_topology(top);
}
```

Finally, the Parallelization class:

```
class Parallelization{
    public:
        Parallelization();
        ~Parallelization();

        void set_topology(Topology top);
    private:
};

Parallelization::Parallelization(){

}
Parallelization::~Parallelization(){

}
void Parallelization::set_topology(Topology top){
    int *s = top.get_sizes();
    for (int i = 0; i < top.get_dim(); i++){
        std::cout << s[i] << " "; // here it prints different numbers, like the vector was never initialized [23144, 352452]
    }
}
```

Shortly, I have a Topology object that gets passed to the Architecture and then to the Parallelization class and there I want to see the internal values from the topology `sizes` vector. Every time the object is passed by value the implicit copy constructor is called and copies only the `dim` field and the address of the `sizes` field, not the whole vector. I wonder why I receive different values, because the vector is still in memory, so it should print the same values.

I mention that if I implement a deep copy-constructor inside the Topology class it works just fine, or if I send the `top` object by reference.

Am I missing something? What could be the cause of this behavior?

Comment: Fyi, `delete sizes` should be `delete [] sizes;`, and of course read this: ["What is the Rule of Three?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). Regarding the "numbers", ask yourself what happens without the deep copy after the *first* `Topology` object is destroyed? What happens to the other `Topology` objects that are toting around the same pointer due to shallow copies? And what happens when *they* `delete sizes` on a now-dangling pointer? Finally, ask yourself why you're not using `std::vector<int>` in the first place.

Comment: Because yor destructor deletes it. Then it deletes it again. You can't outsmart the rule of three/five.

Comment: your example [does not show the problem you mention](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/558b2edb49cf223e), I just commented out `delete sizes;` (see comment by @WhozCraig)

Comment: And your code is ultimately unsafe regardless. you never provide initial values to `dim`, nor `sizes`, in the constructors for `Topology`. Their values are *indeterminate* after successful default construction. Unless `set_sizes` is invoked (itself a recipe for a memory leak if invoked multiple times), the `delete sizes` in the destructor invokes *undefined behavior*. My prior comment closing statement stands. ultimately given what is show here would you be better off scrapping `Topology` entirely and using `typedef std::vector<int> Topology;`. There is little reason to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Ok, about the memory leaks, I did not write the entire code, just some portions enough to let you understand the situation, thank you anyway. The Topology has other fields, i cannot just typedef a vector. :) but the previous comments made me understand he problem. Thank you

Comment: Still, I have another question. The first Topology object that goes out of scope is the one in this function: Parallelization::set_topology(Topology top), so when the vector elements are printed the vector is not deleted anyway.. And to check double deletion I have a a if-condition on a NULL vector in the destructor, so I suppose it should be fine

Comment: "And to check double deletion I have a a if-condition on a NULL vector in the destructor, so I suppose it should be fine" . You are very much mistaken. Again, can't beat the rule of three.

Comment: *And to check double deletion I have a a if-condition on a NULL vector in the destructor, so I suppose it should be fine* OH GOSH THE HORROR.

Comment: when you don't have anything to explain to help someone understand maybe you should keep it quiet :)